# Resultado inesperado em consulta ao banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
class Login{
    public function logar($email,$senha){
        $connect=new DB;
        $connect=$connect->conectar();

        $sql="select * from usuarios where email='$email' and senha='$senha' and status='1' limit 1;";
        $buscar=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        $result=mysqli_num_rows($buscar);
        if ($result==1) {
            $log=1;
            $dados=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar);
            $_SESSION["email"]=$dados["email"];
            $_SESSION["senha"]=$dados["senha"];
            $_SESSION["nivel"]=$dados["nivel"];
            setcookie("logado",1);

        }
        if (isset($log)) {
            $flash="Logado com sucesso!";
        }else{
            $flash="Verifique se as informações inseridas estão corretas!";
        }
        echo $flash;
    }
}
?>
```

Esse código acima existe algo que impossibilite da consulta ser diferente de '1'?
Supomos a seguinte situação: no meu banco de dados há um registro email:'adsvictor@outlook.com' e senha: 'admin'
por que ao executar esse código inserindo as informações corretas a resposta mostrada na tela é "Verifique se as informações inseridas estão corretas!"?

Comment: O `status` desse usuário esta como 1?

Comment: está sim, esse mesmo SQL foi executado no PHP Myadmin

Comment: como são inseridos os dados da conexão? Rodei aqui sem class e sem function logar, inserindo a conexão diretamente e funcionou

Comment: Não porque esta com `limit 1`, então `mysqli_num_rows` vai ser 0 ou 1 sempre

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado aos que comentaram, mas consegui resolver.
A quem interessar, o problema era no banco de dados onde todos registros eram salvos com o status 0, no comando SQL ele dá um SELECT...WHERE status=1.